# Find if key exists in array

Tags: php, arrays

Im working with an API.
With an array i gather data and then i send it to the software i'm working with. Like this:

```
$pers_payload = array(
    'gender' => 'Unknown', //or Male / Female
    'first_name' => $_POST['billing_first_name'],
    'family_name'   => $_POST ['billing_last_name'],
    'email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
    'linked_as_contact_to_organization' => array(
        array(
            'organization_id' => $organization_id, // add the person as a contact to the newly created organization
            'work_email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
            'work_phone' => $_POST['billing_phone']
            )
        ),
    'visiting_address' => array(
        'country_code'          =>  'NL'
        ), // can be extented with other address data
    'postal_address' => array(
        'country_code'      =>  $_POST['billing_country'] 
    )   // can be extented with other address data
);
```

Then i send it like this

```
// add the person to CRM

    $person = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/person',json_encode($pers_payload));
```

When i do a GET call instead of POST like this:

```
$tet = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('GET','/crm/person?q[first_name]=Kevin1');
```

and then `var_dump($tet);`

I believe it returns a so called multi dimensional array:

```
  array(3) {
    ["data"] => array(2) {
        [0] => array(11) {
            ["id"] => string(39)
            "person:067af3bd2045824e62ac579e634623b8" ["interests"] => array(1) {
                [0] => array(3) {
                    ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                    "interest:f278f47e6e9d48b8" ["name"] => string(19)
                    "Actief in Duitsland"
                }
            }["simplicate_url"] => string(51)
            "https://emark.simplicate.nl/crm/person/view?id=3552" ["avatar"] => array(2) {
                ["initials"] => string(2)
                "Kt" ["color"] => string(7)
                "#03e084"
            }["linked_as_contact_to_organization"] => array(1) {
                [0] => array(7) {
                    ["id"] => string(46)
                    "contactperson:0f16f418f1845749c79bebf9e1e753e5" ["organization_id"] => string(45)
                    "organization:8632b86ba41637262e0871767f96f43e" ["name"] => string(9)
                    "testing12" ["work_email"] => string(24)
                    "ma@e-marketingsupport.nl" ["work_phone"] => string(8)
                    "06269684" ["work_mobile"] => string(8)
                    "06269684" ["interests"] => array(16) {
                        [0] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:456e8b19c0079647" ["name"] => string(11)
                            "Twinkle 100"
                        }[1] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:a70e69b83382e85a" ["name"] => string(17)
                            "Bekend merk in NL"
                        }[2] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:ce50f1b5593ac180" ["name"] => string(15)
                            "Cross Border 30"
                        }[3] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:f40eca1b281969d6" ["name"] => string(20)
                            "Meerdere vestigingen"
                        }[4] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:7435d7409a07cefb" ["name"] => string(26)
                            "Meer dan 100k in Duitsland"
                        }[5] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:cc072cea856ea23a" ["name"] => string(17)
                            "B2B leadgeneratie"
                        }[6] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:f278f47e6e9d48b8" ["name"] => string(19)
                            "Actief in Duitsland"
                        }[7] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:9bbeb23d17283595" ["name"] => string(10)
                            "Exporteert"
                        }[8] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:97ed988af66b1abc" ["name"] => string(8)
                            "Debiteur"
                        }[9] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:3e31ffca2394bc38e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(9)
                            "Marketing"
                        }[10] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:706fa5fa92c56081e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(6)
                            "Amazon"
                        }[11] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:05f1a5da1c4c7df2e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(3)
                            "Jur"
                        }[12] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:477554ee16a0c738e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(11)
                            "Vertalingen"
                        }[13] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:f5f1b7512245a3b5e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(5)
                            "Adres"
                        }[14] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:d1123dfaa0073c82e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(4)
                            "GmbH"
                        }[15] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:7d3458131ea89afbe1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(3)
                            "Web"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }["gender"] => string(7)
            "Unknown" ["first_name"] => string(6)
            "Kevin1" ["family_name"] => string(7)
            "testing" ["full_name"] => string(14)
            "Kevin1 testing" ["email"] => string(24)
            "ma@e-marketingsupport.nl" ["phone"] => string(8)
            "06269684"
        }[1] => array(11) {
            ["id"] => string(39)
            "person:067af3bd2045824ea8c16e7ea0baf9d6" ["interests"] => array(1) {
                [0] => array(3) {
                    ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                    "interest:f278f47e6e9d48b8" ["name"] => string(19)
                    "Actief in Duitsland"
                }
            }["simplicate_url"] => string(51)
            "https://emark.simplicate.nl/crm/person/view?id=3553" ["avatar"] => array(2) {
                ["initials"] => string(2)
                "Kt" ["color"] => string(7)
                "#dce1f3"
            }["linked_as_contact_to_organization"] => array(1) {
                [0] => array(7) {
                    ["id"] => string(46)
                    "contactperson:f48fdcaaff0211e728a2e4ccf197900b" ["organization_id"] => string(45)
                    "organization:8632b86ba41637262e0871767f96f43e" ["name"] => string(9)
                    "testing12" ["work_email"] => string(24)
                    "ma@e-marketingsupport.nl" ["work_phone"] => string(8)
                    "06269684" ["work_mobile"] => string(8)
                    "06269684" ["interests"] => array(16) {
                        [0] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:456e8b19c0079647" ["name"] => string(11)
                            "Twinkle 100"
                        }[1] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:a70e69b83382e85a" ["name"] => string(17)
                            "Bekend merk in NL"
                        }[2] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:ce50f1b5593ac180" ["name"] => string(15)
                            "Cross Border 30"
                        }[3] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:f40eca1b281969d6" ["name"] => string(20)
                            "Meerdere vestigingen"
                        }[4] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:7435d7409a07cefb" ["name"] => string(26)
                            "Meer dan 100k in Duitsland"
                        }[5] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:cc072cea856ea23a" ["name"] => string(17)
                            "B2B leadgeneratie"
                        }[6] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:f278f47e6e9d48b8" ["name"] => string(19)
                            "Actief in Duitsland"
                        }[7] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:9bbeb23d17283595" ["name"] => string(10)
                            "Exporteert"
                        }[8] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(25)
                            "interest:97ed988af66b1abc" ["name"] => string(8)
                            "Debiteur"
                        }[9] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:3e31ffca2394bc38e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(9)
                            "Marketing"
                        }[10] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:706fa5fa92c56081e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(6)
                            "Amazon"
                        }[11] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:05f1a5da1c4c7df2e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(3)
                            "Jur"
                        }[12] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:477554ee16a0c738e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(11)
                            "Vertalingen"
                        }[13] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:f5f1b7512245a3b5e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(5)
                            "Adres"
                        }[14] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:d1123dfaa0073c82e1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(4)
                            "GmbH"
                        }[15] => array(3) {
                            ["value"] => bool(false)["id"] => string(41)
                            "interest:7d3458131ea89afbe1bb3149bee8b668" ["name"] => string(3)
                            "Web"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }["gender"] => string(7)
            "Unknown" ["first_name"] => string(6)
            "Kevin1" ["family_name"] => string(7)
            "testing" ["full_name"] => string(14)
            "Kevin1 testing" ["email"] => string(24)
            "ma@e-marketingsupport.nl" ["phone"] => string(8)
            "06269684"
        }
    }["errors"] => NULL["debug"] => NULL
}
```

My problem is i dont want to make the POST request if the array key `first_name` exists inside `$tet`

My attempts:

```
$pers_payload = array(
    'gender' => 'Unknown', //or Male / Female
    'first_name' => $_POST['billing_first_name'],
    'family_name'   => $_POST ['billing_last_name'],
    'email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
    'linked_as_contact_to_organization' => array(
        array(
            'organization_id' => $organization_id, // add the person as a contact to the newly created organization
            'work_email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
            'work_phone' => $_POST['billing_phone']
            )
        ),
    'visiting_address' => array(
        'country_code'          =>  'NL'
        ), // can be extented with other address data
    'postal_address' => array(
        'country_code'      =>  $_POST['billing_country'] 
    )   // can be extented with other address data
);

// add the person to CRM
$tet = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('GET','/crm/person?q[first_name]=Kevin1');

foreach ($tet['data'] as $data) {
    if (array_key_exists('first_name', $data)) {
        echo "found key 'first_name' with value '" . $data['first_name'] . "'\n";
    } else {
        // perform your post request
         $person = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/person',json_encode($pers_payload));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, so you pick the `data` element from the outer array and iterate over its members. In each you check if the key you are looking for exists using either `isset()` or `array_key_exists()`. Looks pretty straight forward to me...

Comment: I'm not really advanced in php some things dont look straight forwards to me sorry :L @arkascha

Comment: Sure, we all learn all the time. All fine. Are you able to follow what I suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pick the data element from the outer array (`$tet['data']`) and iterate over its members. In each you check if the key you are looking for exists using either the [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or the [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function:

```
foreach ($tet['data'] as $data) {
    if (array_key_exists('first_name', $data)) {
        echo "found key 'first_name' with value '" . $data['first_name'] . "'\n";
    } else {
        // perform your post request
    }
}
```

---

If the array is really big and you want to keep memory consumption low so that the code scales well you can prevent copying of the data by only iterating over the array keys, not the complex values:

```
foreach (array_keys($tet['data']) as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists('first_name', $tet['data'][$key])) {
        echo "found key 'first_name' with value '" . $tet['data'][$key]['first_name'] . "'\n";
    } else {
        // perform your post request
    }
}
```

---

Based on your additional comments here it turned out that your actual question is a different one. It probably is enough to add a simple case insensitive string comparison though:

```
foreach (array_keys($tet['data']) as $key) {
    if (   array_key_exists('first_name', $tet['data'][$key])
        && (strcasecmp($tet['data'][$key]['first_name'], 'Kevin1') == 0) ) {
        echo "found key 'first_name' with value '" . $tet['data'][$key]['first_name'] . "'\n";
    } else {
        // perform your post request
    }
}
```

Comment: i know how to solve it but there is an error in your code Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'\n"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: @Kevin.a Thanks for the hint, fixed it, that was a result of my stupid keyboard driver insisting on auto completion ;-)

Comment: still runs the POST request eventho the name i enter exists inside $tet

Comment: @Kevin.a What "name you enter"? Enter where? you did not mention any name in your question, but whether the key "first_name" exists. Can it be that your question does not really ask what you are actually looking for?

Comment: added it to the question.

Comment: If the array key first_name contains a value that already exists dont add it

Comment: That is a completely different question. Sorry. In your question you ask: if the array key first_name exists inside `$tet`.

Comment: And what do you mean by "that already exists" and by "dont add it"? Sorry, but such vague questions are really hard to offer help with...

Comment: Basically if the array key first_name contains the value of for example kevin1 then dont do the post request. ["first_name"] => string(6) "Kevin1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129412/discussion-between-arkascha-and-kevin-a).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885349/check-if-array-values-exist

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_key_exists` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```html
if (array_key_exists('first_name', $pers_payload)) {
    echo 'Can not perform this task';
}else{
 $person = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/person',json_encode($pers_payload));
}
```

Comment: This would search for a _value_ ''first_name", the OP refers to a _key_ with that name.

Comment: Better, but `$pers_payload` is not the array the OP is referring to. At least that is how I understood the question. Just read the last sentence in the question...